# Pressing Enter in fillable form breaks layout

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

I am trying to create a fillable form in Word for Mac 2011.

I have my form all completed and it functions properly, except when the user hits the ENTER key instead of the TAB key, it inserts a line into the form which changes the originally intended layout.

It is my understanding that a Macro to can "tell" the ENTER key to act as a TAB key.  I found the four-part formula for this Macro, but have absolutely no clue how to create it for this form.

Answer (score 1):

By far [this](http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm) is best site which gives step by step instructions for setting up a macro from step one.

I assume you are using the **EnterKeyMacro** from [the MSDN website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211219). In this case, you just need to copy all four blocks of code into the editor and save it. If you save it in the current document only then the macro will only run for this document, however if you choose to save it in the template (Normal.dot) then the macro will be included for any documents you create from that template.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance!!!! You are very kind.

Comment: Thanks Karen. If this lead you to the solution please accept this answer to let others know.